# How can i use hCaptcha verification to protect a table in supabase?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, supabase, row-level-security, supabase-database

In supabase:
I have a table named "ratings", this table have three columns named; "rating", "review" and "name", the "ratings" table is basically there to store the rating info.

The problem:
I want to grant insert access to all the users (not necessarily authenticated/logged in) who have successfully completed the hCpatcha challenge. i do not know the right RLS (Row Level Security) policy and database function to do so.

any help will greatly be appreciated.

I tried the following database function in supabase, with the help of the supabase ai:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hcaptcha_verified()
RETURNS boolean AS $$
DECLARE
  response text;
  api_response json;
BEGIN
  -- Get the hCaptcha response from the request headers
  response := (SELECT headers['x-hcaptcha-response'] FROM jsonb_to_record(supabase.headers()) AS headers);
  RAISE NOTICE 'hCaptcha response: %', response;
  -- Verify the hCaptcha response using the hCaptcha API
  api_response := http_post('https://hcaptcha.com/siteverify', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'secret=0xee72qwefga9f02E0c2178oqldfkwe0bb554f39EC&response=' || response)::json;
  RETURN api_response->>'success'::boolean;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And tried the following RLS Policy along with that function: `hcaptcha_verified()`

Everything in the client-side code is handled with no problems/bugs, i have used the supabase built-in function to insert new data.
Apparently the problem is with the `supabase.headers()` funcntion inside of the `hcaptcha_verified()` function, in this function; `supabase.headers()` is not defined, i do not know how to get the headers from the sent data.

Comment: Why don't you use edge functions to check the captcha and insert in the table? Using http_post in RLS policy is probably a bad idea.

You can use the [service_role](https://blog.mansueli.com/allowing-users-to-invite-others-with-supabase-edge-functions) in the edge function.

Comment: can you be more specific? i do not know the right code to use in edge functions @Mansueli

Comment: Write a [repro] with how you would call the edge function from your code and I'll give you an example here.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this exact topic, here is the solution for protecting inserts on specific tables with hCaptcha:

First, create a function in Supabase SQL editor:

```
DROP function IF EXISTS hcaptcha_verified(captchaToken text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hcaptcha_verified(captchaToken text)
RETURNS boolean AS $$

BEGIN
RETURN (
    SELECT content::jsonb->'success' FROM 
    http_post('https://api.hcaptcha.com/siteverify','secret=YOUR_HCAPTCHA_SECRET>&response=' || captchaToken,'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
)::boolean;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This function takes a hCaptcha token which you generate with the hCaptcha component on your desired frontend framework and checks its validity on hCaptacha's API.

Next, you will create the RLS policy for inserts on your desired tables, you only need to add the CHECK expression like so:

```
hcaptcha_verified(( SELECT ((current_setting('request.headers'::text, true))::json ->> 'x-hcaptcha-token'::text)))
```

The above function returns a boolean, so if the hcaptcha_verified function returns false -> The insert will not occur.

Finally, from your frontend, you insert new entries with the custom header like so (I used React for the following example):

```
createClient(<SUPABASE_URL>, <SUPABASE_ANON_KEY>, {
    global: {
        headers: {
            { 'x-hcaptcha-token': <YOUR_GENERATED_CAPTCHA_TOKEN> }
        }
    },
})
.from('your_table_name')
.insert('your_entry_values')
```

Thanks to [@Amirhosein Nikfallah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21909047/amirhosein-nikfallah) for providing the jumping board for solving this issue.